# Uncommitted changes not showing anything in GitHub

Tags: javascript, git, github

I added an entire JavaScript block of Google Analytics code inside the  tags. I copied the new php file over to my local folder to replace the original php file that didn't have the JavaScript code.

Now I open up GitHub in Windows 8 and GitHub immediately detected the changes and is ready to commit.

My problem however is that there is no preview available that shows the newly added block of Google Analytics JavaScript code in the GitHub preview unlike my other commits that I've done earlier that show the new code that was just added and the old code that was recently removed.

Is that suppose to happen when I'm only adding code and not deleting anything from the old code?

Comment: Have you added the new files to the repository (`git add` or equivalent)?

Comment: I'm working with a drupal framework and I've added Google analytics to the header php file called html.tpl.php but GitHub seems to detect the fact that I've modified that php file however nothing appears in the Before and After changes in the Drupal application.

Comment: You mean changes on your machine are not showing on the GitHub site?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your git.ignore settings . It would be either a file type issue or un tracked files issue.

https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files